# Boost compile error with C2039: time_t is not a member of std

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I have a problem when compile BOOST library using MSVC2015 64-bit on Windows10 64-bit machine.

[image]

I use QT creator as IDE and enable C++14 by using flag
in .pro

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14

here is the part of error that happens in BOOST library: c_time.hpp

```
  //! requires a pointer to a user created std::tm struct
  inline
  static std::tm* localtime(const std::time_t* t, std::tm* result)
  {
    result = std::localtime(t);
    if (!result)
      boost::throw_exception(std::runtime_error("could not convert calendar time to local time"));
    return result;
  }
  //! requires a pointer to a user created std::tm struct
  inline
  static std::tm* gmtime(const std::time_t* t, std::tm* result)
  {
    result = std::gmtime(t);
    if (!result)
      boost::throw_exception(std::runtime_error("could not convert calendar time to UTC time"));
    return result;
  }
```

the compiler yelled that  std::time_t  time_t is not a part of std namespace
also same problem as std::localtime and std::gmtime

I also #include  `<ctime>  <time.h> <cstdlib>` in main before calling all boost libraries but it does not help.

another thing that I found when i tried to trace back to ctime (std c++ file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ctime) here is the part of the code in ctime

```
 #if _GLOBAL_USING && !defined(RC_INVOKED)
_STD_BEGIN
using _CSTD clock_t; using _CSTD size_t;
using _CSTD time_t; using _CSTD tm;
using _CSTD asctime; using _CSTD clock; using _CSTD ctime;
using _CSTD difftime; using _CSTD gmtime; using _CSTD localtime;
using _CSTD mktime; using _CSTD strftime; using _CSTD time;
_STD_END
 #endif /* _GLOBAL_USING */
#endif /* _CTIME_ */code here
```

the error is clock_t: symbol cannot be used in a using declaration error

or

clock_t is not a member of global namespace

I tried with different versions of BOOST library ( boost 1.64, boost 1.65, boost 1.66) The libraries I download from precompile BOOST binaries and install directly to my machine ( https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/ )

here is my pro file from QT creator using MSVC2015 as compiler

```
BOOST_PATH   = C:/local/boost_1_66_0
INCLUDEPATH +=   $${BOOST_PATH}
LIBS        += -L$${BOOST_PATH}/lib64-msvc-14.1
LIBS        += -lboost_atomic-vc140-mt-1_66
LIBS        += -lboost_chrono-vc140-mt-1_66
..........

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

here is what my main.cpp look like. This is a clean QT Application project. There is nothing in other files

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

NOTE: I think the problem is MSVC compiler find function in a wrong namespace. for example  std::localtime() should find in std namespace but the compiler find this function "localtime" in c_time.hpp and it tries to match std::localtime to boost::localtime and give the error.

Comment: "I also #include in main" - what , specifically, did you include ?

Comment: are you missing `#include <boost/chrono.hpp>` somewhere?

Comment: I did #include <boost/chrono.hpp> before  <boost/filesystem.hpp> but no luck

Comment: I think the problem is MSVC link function to wrong namespace. for example std::localtime should be found in std namespace but MSVC find one in BOOST namespace and try to match it. When it cannnot match the compiler show the error.  Not sure how to fix it